# How can I change the design of default elements in Cuba Platform?

Tags: xml, scss-mixins, cuba-platform

I want to change the design of some elements in CUBA. Is it possible to change default elements like filters or tables?
For example I want to make a new order of the elements at the filter section over a table.
I also want to remove all the borders of the table. Already tried to style with stylename="borderless no-vertical-lines no-horizontal-lines" in xml, but there are still borders left.
Anybody here who can help? (I use the hover theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify filter component layout, there is some degree of flexibility - see `cuba.gui.genericFilterControlsLayout` property.
https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/app_properties_reference.html#cuba.gui.genericFilterControlsLayout

To create new styles for existing components, you need to extend theme (hover in your case) in Studio. Invoke in main menu: CUBA -> Advanced -> Manage themes -> Create theme extension.
Then you will be able to define additional styles in the theme .scss files.
See https://doc.cuba-platform.com/studio/#generic_ui_themes
and https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/web_theme_extension.html#web_theme_extension_styles
for more information.